# Error running sample GCM app

Tags: android, android-studio

Following the instructions on Google's web site, I cloned their sample app from github and downloaded the Android Studio.  Next I imported the project as directed and connected my Android phone.  For good measure I also let Android Studio update whatever it wanted.

**I registered and downloaded the google-services.json file from Google's site and placed it, as instructed, in my projects app directory.**

When I run I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

I don't know anything about Android, Studio, or Gradle, so I just made liberal copies of google-services.json all over the project dir hierarchy but nothing worked.

What is the "module root folder" that I need to install google-services.json into?

Comment: It's the app folder. Where you have your app build.gradle. Not your project, your app

Comment: copy the google-services.json file and then right click on your module/app and paste it.

Comment: I'm not seeing where this goes.  In Studio I see an app folder and something called Gradle Scripts.  Looking in my file system I see /AndroidStudioProjects/GCMDemo with subdirs app, gradle, and src.  I put copies of the json file in GCMDemo, app, gradle, gradle/wrapper, src/main/res.  No dice.

Comment: Ok, got it.  As per Google's instructions this is an imported project.  Studio is still referring to where the original files downloaded, not in the AndroidStudioProjects folder.  Copied the json file to the downloaded area and it built fine.

Answer (score 0):

Module root folder is the `app` folder inside the main project folder.
To paste it inside there, first change the project view from `Android` to `Project` (you will find this option above the project files view to the left). Right click on the `app` folder and paste it there. Then recompile.